# FFmpeg upmix command stereo ~> 5.1

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to upmix stereo mkv files with chapter, subtitle, audio and video streams to 5.1 flac with a silent center channel. The audio is a single stereo stream, not two mono streams. I need the resulting mkv to contain a single 6 channel flac stream.

My desired channel layout is FR = FR, FR ~> SR, FL = FL, FL ~> SL, Center silent, LFE = FR+FL

I followed the FFmpeg documentation and was unable to produce the desired mapping.

The command so far (generated with help from Axiom GUI):

```
./ffmpeg -i TestIN.mkv -c:v copy -map 0:v? -map_chapters 0 -c:s copy -map 0:s? -c:a flac -sample_fmt s16 -rematrix_maxval 1.0 -ac 6 -map 0:a:0? -map_metadata 0 -f matroska -threads 0 X:\TestOUT.mkv
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you wanna filter low frequencies before assigning to LFE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [pan filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:a]pan=5.1(side)|FL=FL|FR=FR|LFE<FL+FR|SL=FL|SR=FR[a]" -map 0 -map -0:a -map "[a]" -c copy -c:a flac output.mkv
```

Comment: How to add external mono audio to a channel?

Comment: @Zimba Which channel should the mono be? What is the channel layout that you are adding it to?

Comment: I meant audio for one channel eg. FL is coming from a separate file `-i FL.mp3`

Comment: @Zimba Should be asked as a new question at [su], as there are serial downvoters here at SO for non-programming related questions and answers. I'll see all ffmpeg questions at [su] as well.

Comment: ffmpeg seems to have it's own scripting language, which modifies behaviour of program output, just like `cmd.exe`. Wouldn't this classify the question as programming?

Comment: @Zimba `ffmpeg` is considered to be "general computing software". Programmatic usage of the FFmpeg libraries would be considered on-topic though. You can still ask here, but there is a good chance that you'll get downvoted or that the question will get closed.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid precisely same audio in front and rear they can be filtered:

```
SL=FL-FR|SR=FR-FL
```

I made a test with two channel mono audio and rear channels were muted.

Also, if you want to decrease the volume in rear channels use a decimal factor:

```
SL=0.3*FL-0.3*FR|SR=0.3*FR-0.3*FL
```

I believe there are more sophisticated ways than these but could not find any.